# Liferay and export users into LDAP

Tags: ldap, liferay-6, openldap

I would like to enable the export of the users from Liferay into my OpenLDAP server.
So I enabled the ceckbox on the configuration page and I set the parameters in the LDAP export.

Now, when I try to create a user in Liferay I get:

> Login is temporarily unavailable.

any suggestions?

[image]

this is the bt in java console:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.directory.InvalidAttributeValueException: [LDAP: error code 21 - object
class: value #1 invalid per syntax]; remaining name 'cn=myname,dc=myTest,dc=com'
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3054)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2987)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2794)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_bind(LdapCtx.java:397)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_bind(LdapCtx.java:354)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentContext.p_bind(ComponentContext.java:596)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeContext.bind(PartialCompositeContext.java:1
83)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:404)
        at com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPExporterImpl.addUser(PortalLDAPExporterIm
pl.java:360)
        at com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPExporterImpl.exportToLDAP(PortalLDAPExpor
terImpl.java:252)
        at com.liferay.portal.security.ldap.PortalLDAPExporterUtil.exportToLDAP(PortalLDAPExpor
terUtil.java:62)
        at com.liferay.portal.model.UserListener.exportToLDAP(UserListener.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.model.UserListener.onAfterUpdate(UserListener.java:72)
        ... 91 more
```

Comment: which Liferay version ? each one has a different LDAP bug

Answer (score 0):

Either you have wrong configuration, or you're stuck on a Liferay - LDAP bug.
[Here](http://issues.liferay.com/issues/?jql=project%20=%20LPS%20AND%20component%20=%20%22Infrastructure%20%3E%20LDAP%22%20AND%20status%20=%20Open%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC)'s the list of unresolved issues.

Please provide us an English error message next time, because all I see in your screenshot is... an error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Liferay 6.1 Community there are a few unresolved LDAP related bugs in that version. I faced a number of problems and ultimately it worked by

- Disbaling LDAP export in the LDAP wizard.
- Creating a custom hook which is triggered at user login, creation or any other change to the user object. The hook problematically through Java JNDI look up library exports users into the external AD through LDAP. You can find the hook related code here: http://abhirampal.com/2014/12/20/liferay-ldap-export-to-active-directory-disabled-user-bug/

Feel free to ask if anyone's got any questions.